# Automapper and Open Generics

Tags: generics, automapper, open-generics

I'm trying to use Automapper's Open Generics as described in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics to perform a mapping between User and Account.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
}

public class Account
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

I created the Source and Destination

```
public class Source<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Destination<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to perform the mapping in an AccountService

```
public class AccountService
{
    private User user1 = new User{FirstName = "James", LastName = "Jones", Dob = DateTime.Today, UserId = new Guid("AC482E99-1739-46FE-98B8-8758833EB0D2")};

    static AccountService()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Source<>), typeof(Destination<>));
    }

    public T GetAccountFromUser<T>()
    {
        var source = new Source<User>{ Value = user1 };
        var destination = Mapper.Map<Source<User>, Destination<T>>(source);
        return destination.Value;
    }
}
```

But I get an exception

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: User -> Account OpenGenerics.Console.Models.User ->
>   OpenGenerics.Console.Models.Account
>
> Destination path: Destination`1.Value.Value
>
> Source value: OpenGenerics.Console.Models.User

I confirmed the approach in https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Open-Generics works for `int` and `double`

**Edit**
This might be a solution for me, it's a little messy though.

```
    var mappingExists = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps().FirstOrDefault(m => m.SourceType == typeof (User) && m.DestinationType == typeof (T));
    if (mappingExists == null)
        Mapper.CreateMap<User, T>();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For closed generics, the type parameters also need to be able to be mapped. Add this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, Account>();
```

And you're set.

Comment: Was hoping that was not the case! In my real application the Account is defined in the MVC project and the User is defined in the Service project. The Service project does NOT have reference to the MVC project so I can't map the way you suggest. 
I can do this Mapper.CreateMap<T, Account>(); but this is executed for every call to the GetAccountFromUser<T>() method.

Comment: Ugh. I hate project layouts like this. Just put everything in one project and use folders.

Comment: That ship has sailed!

Comment: Added a potential solution to the question